# Splitting String with " ' " but NOT " ?' "

Tags: regex, vb.net, split

I want to split a String whereever the `'` character is present **unless** there is a question mark in front of it(`?'`) - in that case I **don't** want to split.
What's the best way to go about doing that?
I'm splitting like so (if the delimiter is a Char):

```
message.Split(New Char() {"'"C})
```

And if it's a String:

```
message.Split(New String() {"break"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Do I then have to test each item in the given array to see if it ends with a `?` char, and then concatenate the Strings again - that just doesn't seem like an optimal solution..?
Do you have to make a regular expression, and how would you do that in vb.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a `Regex.Split` with a `(?<!\?)'` regex:

```
Regex.Split(message, "(?<!\?)'")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO2mL8/1)

The `(?<!\?)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if a literal `?` appears right to the left of the single apostrophe.

In VB.NET, you can use Linq to remove any empty strings you get with this regex split:

```
Dim message As String = "'sss?'ss'"
Dim my_result() As String = Regex.Split(message, "(?<!\?)'") _
        .Where(Function(strn As String) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strn) = False) _
        .ToArray()
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", my_result))
' => sss?'ss
```

[image]